# How to process payments made by Saved cc

Tags: payment, payment-methods, payment-gateway

By mistake I haven't disabled Save cc as a payment method. Someone made a purchase using that method.

How do I process that order?

What do I need to receive that money because there is no place to enter my bank account.

Should I use credit card info and process that payment manually?

Is money withdrawn from the clients cc and if yes -

Where did it went?

Can I cancel that transaction safely so my client is not charged and that money gone who knows where?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cancel the order and ask your customer to place it again (it won't generate any charges in your customer credit card). To avoid issues you can also place the order via admin with your customer over the phone using the payment method you have configured.